# Adding UITableViewCell Image on button press

Tags: ios, uitableview, button

Is there a way to add an image to my `UITableViewCell` when I push a certain button?

Comment: Yes there is, though if you could provide more detail of what you've tried, what you're struggling with etc, post some code that you've tried then people will be able to point you in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html, a UITableViewCell has a property called imageView which is a UIImageView meaning that all you need to do is create a UIImageView and set the UITableViewCell's imageView property to that of your UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

Yes by creating a subclass of UITableViewCell, you can create tableviewcells in any format you want -  Your subclass needs to know if the user pressed the button - many ways to do this -  a plist,  NSUserdefault or even a property in the TableViewCell subclass

Make sure your TableView delegate methods particularly CellForRowAtIndexpath calls your custom class.

Just [Tableview reloaddata] every time the button is toggled.

A good reference is the Elements sample app from apple.